# shared hosting CPanel linum godaddy

Tags: php, xml, ini, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting Cpanel Linux

I am trying to parse a XML file with over 3000 products in it.. I am getting a 500 Internal error while I am trying to parse it..
I go to "Select PHP version" through the Dashboard and "Switch to PHP Options"
I have these settings:
max_execution_time: 6000
memory_limit: 512M
post_max_size 128MB
upload_max_filesize 512MB

my file is almost 2MB so I guess the problem is not there.. The execution time stops the parsing at 2 minutes..
I have already upload a custom file php.ini with this inside:
max_execution_time: 6000
I have also tried to upload a file named user.ini, with the same value.. but nothing works..
I have PHP version 5.6

the only value at 120 (seconds I guess) is this: realpath_cache_ttl
but I do not know what this is...
Any ideas please?

*In localhost xampp, I had the same problem, but by increasing the value of max_execution_time at 6000 the problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I could not find any solution with godaddy.. They said everything are wokring fine in the server.. So, I tried to find a better optimized solution to my problem and I found the XMLReader:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($product_xml_link);
    while($reader->read()) {
        if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'product' ) {
         //..do the proccess here..whatever you want..
         //for example
         $product = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXml());
         $pid = $product->id;
         $name = $product->name;
        ...
        ...
}
```

There are lots of links that you could read of about XMLReader, which is also better for large XML files..

Now, I could INSERT all the XML Elements into DB without any 500 internal errors.
*Although my XML is not to big..about 3.500 products